# shared lib libmp.so.3 not found

Tags: shared-library

I am trying to run the software Synopsys-Sentaurus on x64 machine with Ubuntu 15.

I get the error "unable to open shared lib libmp.so.3..."

the libg gmp seems to be installed.

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: You're sure you have `libgmp-dev` installed?

Comment: `libgmp.so.3` or `libmp.so.3`

Answer (score 1):

When you run Sentaurus Project/Operation/Run, you can encounter the libmp.so.3 error below:

```
sprocess: error while loading shared libraries: libmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

1. Install **libmp3-5.0.5-48.1.x86_64.rpm**. Google this or see [this link](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23600931/dir/centos_5/com/libmp3-5.0.5-48.1.x86_64.rpm.html) to download the package and see this [link for](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-an-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-linux/) the instruction to install the RPM package on Ubuntu
2. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libmp.so.3 /usr/lib/libmp.so.3`

Also, you can find an answer [here](http://ekim616.blogspot.com/p/cadence-virtuoso-on-kubuntu-ubuntu-1504.html) for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Here's how I solved it. First download **Libgmp3c2** from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/libgmp3c2) and then install the deb package using dpgk as follows

```
sudo dpkg -i <path_to_deb_file>
```

You can check the installation using

```
find /usr/lib/ -name "libgmp*"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.2

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3
```